# How can get the object return by command executed using subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess

How can get the object return by command executed using subprocess.Popen()

I have a class says student. I want to execute following command using subprocess.Popen() and access `st1`

```
st1 = student(parameters)
```

Code which I am trying is :

```
Mycmd = "st1 = student(parameters)"
p = subprocess.Popen(["python"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
return_object = p.communicate(Mycmd.encode())
```

Comment: If you want to return the Popen object, return `p` -- not `p.communicate()`. If that's _not_ what you want, modify your question to be more clear.

Comment: ...in general, though, UNIX commands don't return objects. They write to file descriptors, and they return an exit status (a number). If you want to pass an "object" through, that typically means you need to serialize it within the subprocess and deserialize it in the parent.

Comment: p is result of executing command "python" I want the the return object st1 which is output of "st1 = student(parameters)"  please specify what else do you require to make it more clear

Comment: What part of "UNIX commands don't return objects" is unclear?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `subprocess.Popen()` to run another Python script?  It looks to me as if you have two Python scripts and you haven't figured out any other way to use code in one script from the other script.  If this is the case then using `subprocess` is most definitely the wrong way to proceed here.

Comment: ...in particular, if you don't have a reason to be executing this out-of-process, you can import the other file as a module and access variables it defines that way. But if you want to know how to access another script's objects with `subprocess.Popen()`, absent a serialization/deserialization layer, the answer is "you can't".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the object, you should make a class and the instantiate to get the objects. Subprocess only can give you stdout content and exit status code.

To the shell that runs your `python` command a python object has no meaning.

The approach you are using could only be effective if after creating your `student` object, you serialize it using the `pickle` module and in your main program you deserialize it from the stdout capture. But I insist, this is not the way python is intended to be used.

Comment: ok.. I can add st1 = student(parameters) in my code then can I execute p = subprocess.Popen(["st1.getparam()"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

Comment: it wont work - you don't execute python methods using Popen. you need to read all the replys again ... and maybe read the python tutorial again. What is making you think you need another process ?